# Is「球が速い」a common expression?

Tags: translation, word-choice, usage, nuances, expressions

I'm reading [this interview with a voice actress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niR1p.jpg), and this phrase came up pretty much out of context from the interviewer (in the sense that they weren't talking about baseball or a literal ball).

> -- さすがにもっといますよ！（笑）
>
> [interviewee] : でも、「私はファンめっちゃいる」って思っちゃって、天狗にはなりたくないし……。　常に初心の心を忘れずに、感謝を忘れずに生きていこうと思っています。
>
> -- **球{たま｝が速｛はや｝いです**！

Is this perhaps an alternative to saying ”**ストレート**” /the interviewee gave a "straight" answer?

Comment: @user27280 I'd say 玉 would be the more common kanji associated with たま, whereas 球 I almost always hear as きゅう (ie 速球{そっきゅう})

Comment: @気になるあの娘 Both "玉" and "球" are pronounced as "たま". Their meanings are close.

Comment: @気になるあの娘 Is there any source (e.g. URL) of this interview? I want to know the context.

Comment: @nekketsuuu yes, but because I was unfamiliar with the phrase I went with this reading arbitrarily. here's a passage https://imgur.com/oi0RoOF

Comment: @気になるあの娘　Using a 漢語 for your example, which generally uses an 音読み reading does not mean that it won't be pronounced as 訓読み when it is by itself. See the dictionary reference [here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/138632/meaning/m0u/). It is under 1-1-㋓.

Comment: @user27280 thanks for clearing that up

Comment: Can you show us one page before your link page?

Comment: @YuuichiTam you mean I should link the whole interview? (the hyperlink was an edit done by someone else)

Comment: No, I want to know one or two pages  before your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a baseball metaphor. [剛速球](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%89%9B%E9%80%9F%E7%90%83), [直球](http://jisho.org/search/%E7%9B%B4%E7%90%83), ストレート or 速い球 refers to a straight or unreserved statement from someone. The opposing idea is [変化球](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%A4%89%E5%8C%96%E7%90%83), which refers to a tricky statement. I think 変化球 is far more common as metaphorical expressions. Note that in baseball contexts, 球 is always read  たま. 球 is read きゅう in mathematical contexts ("sphere"). 玉 (たま) refers to a precious "orb" or "gem".

What she has said in the interview is not particularly a 速い球 to me because that is almost a cliché used by many people near the end of interview sessions. Maybe the interviewer was surprised at the "straight" comment while he had expected something more unique and "fresh" as an アイドル声優. (She is a new seiyu, and normally she doesn't have to worry about forgetting her 初心 and 感謝 yet.)

Comment: by the by, @naruto what does she mean by 初心の心 here. "Innocence" or would it be her "Original Intentions"?

Comment: 初心 refers to (good) feelings a newbie has, typically a sense of tension and a respect for a veteran.

Comment: 「[初心]{しょしん}の[心]{こころ}」って、重言ですよね。。たぶん・・・

Comment: @Chocolate 重言という "redundant" ですか?